# File not found hashtag problem

Tags: url, hashtag

My JQM app has a page in it called "settings" which has three buttons serving as links to other pages. One of those pages is called "tracks" and the code for it is below.

```
<a href="#tracks" data-role="button">Control your relaxation resources</a>
```

When I click this button I get a "File not found" error and the browser is pointing to the "file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/SITES/jQuery%20Mobile%20Form/tracks#tracks" url rather than the "file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/SITES/jQuery%20Mobile%20Form/index.html#tracks" url. I'm using FF but it happens in all browsers and it also happens when running on the test website.

The navigation works for the other two buttons on the page.

The behavior occurs regardless of what name I give the page.

I know I've seen this problem discussed but can't find the answer to it, so my apologies in advance it this is a duplicate or triplicate.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Updating to beta 2 of JQM took care of this problem. Don't know why but it is resolved now.